# How to pass the single link in a nested URL scrape?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a problem with Scrapy, I'm scraping a subpage with a link that I obtained in the main page.

Every comic has is own page, so I tried to open the page for every item and scrape the price.

This is the spider:

```py
class PaniniSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spiderP"
    start_urls = ["http://comics.panini.it/store/pub_ita_it/magazines.html"]

    def parse(self, response):
        # Get all the <a> tags
        for sel in response.xpath("//div[@class='list-group']//h3/a"):
            l = ItemLoader(item=ComicscraperItem(), selector=sel)
            l.add_xpath('title', './text()')
            l.add_xpath('link', './@href')

            request = scrapy.Request(sel.xpath('./@href').extract_first(), callback=self.parse_isbn, dont_filter=True)
            request.meta['l'] = l
            yield request

    def parse_isbn(self, response):
        l = response.meta['l']
        l.add_xpath('price', "//p[@class='special-price']//span/text()")
        return l.load_item()
```

The problem is about the link, the outpust is similar to this:

```sh
{"title": "Spider-Man 14", "link": ["http://comics.panini.it/store/pub_ita_it/mmmsm014isbn-it-marvel-masterworks-spider-man-marvel-masterworks-spider.html"], "price": ["\n                    \u20ac\u00a022,50                ", "\n                    \u20ac\u00a076,50                ", "\n                    \u20ac\u00a022,50                ", "\n                    \u20ac\u00a022,50                ", "\n                    \u20ac\u00a022,50                ", "\n                    \u20ac\u00a018,00
{"title": "Avenger di John Byrne", "link": ["http://comics.panini.it/store/pub_ita_it/momae005isbn-it-omnibus-avengers-epic-collecti-marvel-omnibus-avengers-by.html"], "price": ["\n                    \u20ac\u00a022,50                ", "\n                    \u20ac\u00a076,50                ", "\n                    \u20ac\u00a022,50
```

In short, the request passes the list of the link of every item, so the price is not unique, but the result of the list.

How can I pass only the link of the relative item and store the price for every item?

Comment: maybe use `response.xpath()` instead of `l.add_xpath('price')`

Comment: OR maybe you should get `sel =  response.xpath('//div[@id="products-list"]/div') ` and later for title `'.//h3/a/text()', for link './/h3/a/@href' and for price '".//p[@class='special-price']//span/text()"` and then you don't need to load subpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two methods:

Use `response.xpath` to get it in subpage

```
def parse_isbn(self, response):
    l = response.meta['l']

    price = response.xpath("//p[@class='special-price']//span/text()")
    # ... do something with price ...

    return l.load_item()
```

Or on main page get divs which have all needed information - title, link and price

```
for sel in response.xpath('//div[@id="products-list"]/div'):
    l.add_xpath('title', './/h3/a/text()')
    l.add_xpath('link', './/h3/a/@href')
    l.add_xpath('price', './/p[@class="special-price"]//span/text()')
```

and then you don't have to use `parse_isbn`

---

For test I used standalone script which you can put in one file and run without creating project.

It gets prices correctly.

```
import scrapy

def clean(text):
    text = text.replace('\xa0', ' ')
    text = text.strip().split('\n')
    text = ' '.join(x.strip() for x in text)
    return text

class PaniniSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "spiderP"
    start_urls = ["http://comics.panini.it/store/pub_ita_it/magazines.html"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//div[@id="products-list"]/div'):
            yield {
                'title': clean(sel.xpath('.//h3/a/text()').get()),
                'link':  clean(sel.xpath('.//h3/a/@href').get()),
                'price': clean(sel.xpath('.//p[@class="special-price"]//span/text()').get()),
            }     

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', # 
})
c.crawl(PaniniSpider)
c.start()
```

---

**EDIT:** If you have to load other page then you can use `add_value` with `response.xpath().get()` instead of `add_xpath`

```
def parse_isbn(self, response):
    l = response.meta['l']

    l.add_value('price', response.xpath("//p[@class='special-price']//span/text()").get())

    return l.load_item()
```

Full example:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose

def clean(text):
    text = text.replace('\xa0', ' ')
    text = text.strip().split('\n')
    text = ' '.join(x.strip() for x in text)
    return text

class ComicscraperItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(clean))
    link = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(clean))

class PaniniSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "spiderP"
    start_urls = ["http://comics.panini.it/store/pub_ita_it/magazines.html"]

    def parse(self, response):
        # Get all the <a> tags
        for sel in response.xpath("//div[@class='list-group']//h3/a"):
            l = ItemLoader(item=ComicscraperItem(), selector=sel)
            l.add_xpath('title', './text()')
            l.add_xpath('link', './@href')

            request = scrapy.Request(sel.xpath('./@href').extract_first(), callback=self.parse_isbn, dont_filter=True)
            request.meta['l'] = l
            yield request

    def parse_isbn(self, response):
        l = response.meta['l']
        l.add_value('price', response.xpath("//p[@class='special-price']//span/text()").get())
        return l.load_item()   

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', # 
})
c.crawl(PaniniSpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: There are some additional info like author and pages that are not in the main page, so i must scrape from the second page.

Comment: so in second page use `response.xpath` to use HTML from second page.

Comment: I tried to do it and I tried to print the result like this: `print(response.xpath("//p[@class='special-price']//span/text()").get())`
But the price(taken from second page) is unaligned(like before)....
I have another question, how can i save the result of the selector(just written up) in the itemloader(i want to visualize it in a file so i need to save it in the item that the itemloader is using)?

Comment: `ItemLoader` has methods to clean items but `xpath().get()` doesn't clean it and you have to do it manually.

Comment: it seems you can use `response.xpath` in  `app_path('price', response.xpath(...))` and then it uses HTML from correct page. I don't use `Item` to keep data so I can't use `ItemLoader` to confirt it.

Comment: correction - it has to be `add_value` instead of `add_path`

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect, if you want update your post so i can mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score -1):

Create your item loader by inheriting scrapy's item loader and apply default_output_processor = TakeFirst()

eg.

```
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst


class DefaultItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    link_output_processor = TakeFirst()
```

You can also refer to my project https://github.com/yashpokar/amazon-crawler/blob/master/amazon/loaders.py

Comment: I used your solution but the value that it takes is the first of the list every time, so the price is equal for all of the items. I'm trying to align the result, like deleting the first element of the selector when it is taken but i don't know how to do... and i don't know if there is a better method to do that

Comment: @Fabio I've changed the answer, I would suggest you to look at the docs once. This is not a Q/A Website. You should try something on your own.

Comment: I do it, but you simple copy and paste from your source without giving some explanation that is a bad behavior. 
I tried to implement the inheriting of the ItemLoader like you suggest (that is not necessary because i had wrote the input processor and the output processor for the item) but the result didn't change.
The solution that fit better is about using `add_value` that pass to the next value of the selector every iteration (like furas suggest)